# Flask SQLAlchemy query (order_by)

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't figure this out, I've done little work before with SQLAlchemy, but Flask SQLAlchemy seems to work very differently, and I can't find much about it online or on the documentation.

Basically, I want to pull one item from the database, and I have done this:

```
current_word = WordOfDay.query.order_by("WordOfDay.created_date").limit(1)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'word_of_the_day'
```

Why does it keep referring to 'BaseQuery' and how can I get around this? Other queries seem to work such as `.query.get(id)`...

Comment: you could use the desc function with the order_by function i use it all the time and it works well

Comment: Hmm but I still get the error, I'm not sure why it's giving me BaseQuery error when it seems correct to me

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including your model definitions, as well as the full stack trace.

Comment: This might be a mismatch from your model definition and to your database table. You might have specified a column called word_of_the_day in your model, but forgot a migration.